# StrToTime not getting time according to local

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys I'm using to `strtotime` to convert the date but the problem that I'm facing is it sets the time to 19:00:00 which is wrong. I am sending a date string and then giving it to strtotime and it set the time itself. Right now my time is 11:58 but it is storing the time as 19:00. Please tell me why am I facing this error. Here is the code: `strtotime($s_date)` `$s_date` contains only a date string `strtotime` sets the time

the date string that I'm sending is this `03/04/2016`

**HTML**

```
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="starts" data-container="#addNewEvent"
              data-plugin="datepicker">
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  base_url + "apps/calendar/insertCalendar",
          async : false,
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {

            'start': $('#starts').val(),
            'end': $('#ends').val(),
            'title': $('#addTitle').val(),
            'description': $('#addDescription').val(),
            'type':type
           },
          success: function(mark_up){
            toastr.options = {positionClass: 'toast-top-center'};
            toastr.success('Your reminder has been created', 'Reminder created');
            window.location.reload();
          }
        });
```

**Controller Method**

```
 public function insertCalendar(){
   $s_date = $_POST["start"];
   $p = strtotime($s_date);
   error_log($p)
 }
```

one thing more I'm stroing it in mongodb so the object that I get from strtotime i convert them into `new MongoDate(strtotime($s_date))`

Comment: @Gardezi You need to set `timezone`, from where you are ..?

Comment: What you have tried till now ? Post some code please

Comment: @Yash I'm from Asia/Karachi.  which is set

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');

Comment: @plum I have set this  `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi')` to my time zone;

Comment: @Gardezi change that to your place man which is Asia/Karachi as you said

Comment: @Plum yes that is correct

Comment: @Gardezi check here it has the available timezone http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: @Plum my timezone is available in that list

Comment: Show us the full date string you're sending to `strtotime()`. Or better yet..  show us the actual code that you use.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I using a date picker and using a ajax call to send back the date that has been set back to the controller and I have added the date string

Comment: Post your code. This is simply vague

Comment: Yes.. but you have the code `strtotime()` somewhere in your code I presume? Always post the code. Is that date string a dump of what your PHP-file receives from the datepicker?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson code added

Comment: @Gardezi what is dateformat over here `m/d/Y` or `d/m/Y`

Comment: @Uchiha mydate format is `m/d/Y`

Comment: you're storing the date in `$s_date` and then use `$_date` in the call to `strtotime()`

Comment: @Uchiha Iam stroing it in mongodb to so the object that I get from strtotime I convert it into mongodate object to using `new Mongodate` and passing the object that I get from strtotime into `mongodate`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so that was a typing copying mistake. I have updated the code

Comment: What is the datatype of your date field

Comment: If you want us to help you with your code... copy *the actual code*, don't rewrite it..   hard to find typos in the real code if we only get to see a copy..

Comment: @Uchiha according to db it's `ISODate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to set first `timezone`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

then you can get time and date using below code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); /* Current date and time*/
echo date('Y-m-d');  /* Current date */
echo date('h:i:s');  /* Current time */
```

If you want to convert date into required format.
For Example. `03/04/2016`, so use

```
$s_date = '03/04/2016';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($s_date)); /* Convert date into mysql date format */
```

You will get date according to `Y-m-d` format of mysql like `2016-03-04`.

Now you want user provided date with current time, then you should use

```
$s_date = '03/04/2016'.' '.date('h:i:s');
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($s_date));
```

This will solve you problem.

Comment: this will not store the time ?

Comment: so use variable to store your current time.

Comment: @Gardezi you can store time along with your date. use `$date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($s_date));` It will take date you want to store and current time according to timezone.

Comment: Yash I am also storing the strtotime in mongodb. Before I send it to the db I am converting the strtotime object to mongoDate like this `new MongoDate(date('m-d-y-h:i:s',strtotime($s_date)))` but what is stores in db is this `ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:03.0Z")`

Comment: @Gardezi i updated the code for mogodb. Hope this will  help you.

Comment: Yash I'm still getting the time like this `ISODate("2016-03-03T19:00:00.0Z")` where as my local  time is 12:52 PM. Now I know that mongo stores according to UTC. Where I live it is 5 hours ahead of UTC so it should have stored the time 7:52 AM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105344/discussion-between-yash-and-gardezi).